# How do you distinguish between modules and controllers in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework

For example, we need to add a news component to a website, and it will have add/edit/delete/listing functions. Which option will you go for?

Option1:

modules
- admin
 
   controllers
     NewsController (addAction, editAction, deleteAction, listAction, etc)
- default
   controllers
     NewsController (listAction)

Option2:

modules
- admin
- default
- news
   controllers
     IndexController (addAction, editAction, deleteAction, listAction, etc)
   models
   views

Any better ideas?

Comment: Also see [Admin screens in Zend: controller or module?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/721938/admin-screens-in-zend-controller-or-module)

Comment: Thanks for the link, David. I got some ideas from that.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar to option 1.

Option 2 is mixing frontend and backend logic so it gets messy.

If you're working on an very small app, maybe got with option 2 but separate add, edit, delete into an AdminController within the news module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I also use option 1 atm. I think if the controller becomes too complicated, then it would be better convert it to a "Module".